# How to check if the input into an array failed?

Tags: c++, arrays, input

I'm doing a homework assignment and one function I need to write is a simple function that allows the user to input an int that will go into an array. One of the conditions though is to check if the input failed, and if it did, end the the program with a 'die' function. How do I check if the input was not put into the array? Should I just check that the input was an int? Thanks for the help.

```
void input( unsigned a[], unsigned elements ){


    for (unsigned i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
        cout << "Enter a number for index #" << i <<" in the array:" << endl;
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    // Add die function if this function fails...

}

bool die(const string &msg) {
    cerr <<endl << "fatal error: " <<msg <<endl;
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

Comment: Why don't you input as a string, then check if the string is a valid number.

Comment: The function prototype has to be the same as the professor's.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: well, you could iterate through array for the value of `i` or utilize `try` and `catch` in some way. Since it is homework, I do not want to be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (!(cin >> a[i])) { die("boo"); }
```

Comment: What if the input was zero?

Comment: Well, zero is a valid input, isn't it? (It is an unsigned integer)

Comment: Ok, I was just checking. I've used (!(statement)) in the past but may be unsure of exactly what it means. I thought it meant "if input was zero." Is that wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1681673: The result of `cin >> a[i]` is the stream object, not the integer. So you're testing whether the stream has failed. *Only* if the stream is still good are you even allowed to touch the integer.

Comment: OH. So it's checking whether or not a stream occurred. Got it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

void input( unsigned a[], unsigned elements )
   {

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
    cout << "Enter a number for index #" << i <<" in the array:" << endl;
    cin >> a[i] || die("Error");
}
```